# Regressing on only the positive part of a vector

Tags: regression, finance

I have an interesting question, with its original application in finance. Suppose I have a stock return $Y$, and a set of independent variables (other tradable assets) $X$. Typically, one *hedges* Y with X by finding the least squares solution to regressing $Y$ on $X$. Thus $Y - X\beta$ is approximately zero.

But what if we instead decompose $Y = Y^{+} + Y^{-}$, where $Y^{+}$ is the vector of *positive* components of $Y$ and zero otherwise, likewise for $Y^{-}$. If we then regress $Y^{-}$ onto $X$, then $Y - X\beta_{neg}$ only hedges the negative values, and exposes us to gains from positive values of $Y$ as

$$Y - X\beta_{neg}$$
$$ = Y^{+} + ( Y^{-} - X\beta_{neg} )$$ 
$$ \approx Y^{+} $$

This sounds great to hedge downside risk, but it doesn't really work in practice unfortunately. Any advice?

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by writing $Y-X\beta_{neg}$? You had regressed $Y^{-}$ on the $X$'s corresponding to the negative $Y$'s if I understand you correctly.

Comment: You are correct. I used $\beta_{neg}$ to differentiate it from the $\beta$ above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe I have a few reasons why this doesn't work:

The most obvious is that $Y^{+,-}|X$ is definitely not normally distributed. The second reason is that my least squares line is linear (obviously), but it should have a kink (ideally) to incorporate the zero values.